# How to put random string along with loading effect

Tags: php, html, random

```
if(!function_exists('qode_loading_spinner_wave')) {
function qode_loading_spinner_wave() {
    $html = '';
    $html .= '<div class="wave">';
    $html .= '<div class="bounce1"></div>';
    $html .= '<div class="bounce2"></div>';
    $html .= '<div class="bounce3"></div>';
    $html .= '</div>';

    return $html;
}
```

}

Above codes is retrieved from a php file that show a loading effect whenever a new page load. I want to add random string from the list by the way in [this post:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4730921/4229234) https://stackoverflow.com/a/4730921/4229234

I want to know how to add random string that appear along with the loading effect. I tried to add

> $html .= 'echo $randomThings[mt_rand(0,count($randomThings)-1)];';

between main div "wave" tag but it doesn't work. Thanks in advance

Comment: `$html = str_replace('<div class="wave">', '<div class="wave"> . $randomThings');` Does this helps you?

Comment: You don't need to have the echo in the string itself

Comment: Thanks Rizier123 for your quick response. When I add your code, it leads to remove or hidden ( i don't know) loading effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add random after the `<div class="wave">` tag, this should work:

```
$html = '';
$html .= '<div class="wave">';
$random_key = mt_rand(0, count($randomThings) - 1);
$html .= $randomThings[$random_key];
$html .= '<div class="bounce1"></div>';
$html .= '<div class="bounce2"></div>';
$html .= '<div class="bounce3"></div>';
$html .= '</div>';

return $html;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I figured out and now it works perfectly. Thanks again :).